# Kable cell_spec formatting removes row labels of table

Tags: r, r-markdown, kable, kableextra

In R markdown, I'm trying to conditionally format an html table using kable package. I have a table bigT_output that looks like this
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r5Vdv.png)

I use Kable to format it using this code

```
    kable(bigT_output[,1:7], booktabs=TRUE, align="c") %>% 
  pack_rows(
    index = c("Performance Standard" = 1, "Percentile Rank (max 100)" = 3, "Productivity" = 2)
    )%>% 
  kable_styling(bootstrap_options = "hover")
```

And it makes this nice looking table in the html output:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h0b2Q.png)

Ideally I'd like to format the whole first row (Grade) to change background depending on whether it's ME, BE, DE, etc. But just to test, I'm trying to change the background of just one column. When I use cell_spec, it removes all the row labels and ignores my other kable format options as shown below:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cTjrN.png)

Here's that code:

```
    bigT_output %>%
mutate(Merch = cell_spec(Merch, "html", background="green")) %>%
kable(bigT_output[,1:7], booktabs=TRUE, align="c") %>% 
  pack_rows(
    index = c("Performance Standard" = 1, "Percentile Rank (max 100)" = 3, "Productivity" = 2)
    )%>% 
  kable_styling(bootstrap_options = "hover")
```

How can I both make my table pretty with subheadings AND format a certain row of it without losing row labels? I keep getting errors with everything I try. Thank you for reading.

Answer (score 0):

The solution was to save the row names in the function that creates the table. Then call the function, convert to dataframe, mutate to get the colors (mutate_all(funs()), add in row names (`rownames<-`(bigT_row_names)), and then apply kable_styling.